# expand / and /home partitions

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I can't seem to make them apply in my case. My current situation is this

[image: gparted view]

My hope is to shrink the swap partition and add most of it to sda5 and 6 Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? As I see it a `swap` shrink might expand `sda5` as that would place the free space beside it. But not sure about `sda6`

Comment: im happy to get rid of most of the swap. But where would I go from there? sda4 is root (afaik). Also, thx for embedding the picture

Comment: Basically, after you shrink the swap you must first move the two other partitions, as partitions can only be extended to the right, not to the left.

Comment: Shrink the swap as yours is too large for a swap partition. Shrink using gparted in a live session, then lets see what we get out of it.

Comment: I'm writing this from a live session haha. I can shrink the swap to nothing. If i try to move or resize sda5 i get

 You have queued an operation to move the start sector of partition /dev/sda5.  Failure to boot is most likely to occur if you move the GNU/Linux partition containing /boot, or if you move the Windows system partition C:.
You can learn how to repair the boot configuration in the GParted FAQ.

Comment: Since /dev/sda7 is the `swap` partition, I would suggest deleting it.  Convert the `unallocated` space into the `swap` partition. Resize from that configuration.  See this post: ["How Big Should Your Page File or Swap Partition Be?"]( https://www.howtogeek.com/196238/how-big-should-your-page-file-or-swap-partition-be/).

Comment: In the live session running Gparted select `sda7` with right-click and choose `Swapoff`. Now you should be able to resize `sda7`, then move `sda5` to the left, then increase the size of `sda5`, then move `sda6` to the left, then increase size of `sda6`. This way partition-order and UUID's of partitions are unchanged and booting should work without editing `/etc/fstab` and/or reinstalling Grub.

Comment: I just went for it (ignoring warnings) as George, fkraiem and mook765 suggested and it seems to have worked without problems. Can't upvote or accept answer but if someone does, I'm happy to. Thanks! :]